# Add a tensor only to a part of another tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to add two tensors, one with a shape multiple of the other in the depth direction. Here an example

```
t1 = tf.constant(3, shape=[2, 2, 2], dtype=tf.float32)
t2 = tf.constant(1, shape=[2, 2, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
```

I want to use something like `tf.add` to add the second tensor to the first but only in the first layer of the third component of the shape. With numbers

```
t1 = [[[3, 3], [3, 3]],
      [[3, 3], [3, 3]]]
t2 = [[[1, 1], [1, 1]]]

output = [[[4, 4], [4, 4]],
          [[3, 3], [3, 3]]]
```

Is there a built-in function to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the first '*column*' of `t1` with `t2` and then concat it with the rest columns of `t1`:

```
t1 = tf.constant(3, shape=[2, 2, 2], dtype=tf.float32)
t2 = tf.constant(1, shape=[2, 2, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
tf.InteractiveSession()

tf.concat((t1[...,0:1] + t2, t1[...,1:]), axis=2).eval()

#array([[[4., 3.],
#        [4., 3.]],

#       [[4., 3.],
#        [4., 3.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Notice your second example `t2` has a different shape, i.e. `(1,2,2)` instead of `(2,2,1)`, in which case, slice and concat by the first axis:

```
tf.concat((t1[0:1] + t2, t1[1:]), axis=0).eval()

#array([[[4., 4.],
#        [4., 4.]],

#       [[3., 3.],
#        [3., 3.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Yes, I explained it wrong but your method works! Thanks